# matplotlib using imageio - TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 408, 612) for image data

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, typeerror

I want to do image processing using matplotlib.
Here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/fishsampleimages/fish1.jpg')

# io.imwrite("readfish1.jpg", img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

I got the error and output as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4abe12c2ad85> in <module>()
      5 
      6 # io.imwrite("readfish1.jpg", img)
----> 7 plt.imshow(img)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    697                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
    698             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
--> 699                             .format(self._A.shape))
    700 
    701         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 408, 612) for image data
```

[image]

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your source file. A standard image would load with a shape of (height, width, num_colors) so when you do

```
img.shape
```

you should get a result of

```
(612,408,3)
```

in your case, the shape seems to be backwards.

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 408, 612) for image data
```

either try with another image or you can reshape the image before showing it

```
img_reshaped = img.reshape(612,408,3)
plt.imshow(img_reshaped)
```

This may show your image correctly, else you would have to go to the source of the image and make sure it is written correctly.

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue where the predicted mask has the dimensions of (2023, 2023, 256). Where (2023,2023,3) is the dimensions of the input image. Thanks & Best Regards Schroter Michael